# SSO/Cookies/Authentication: Is this safe?

Tags: security, cookies, coldfusion, single-sign-on

So this sort of goes with my question: [Authentication Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668248/authentication-cookie)

Our current organization has a CAS SSO system. I manage multiple applications that all use their own sessions in ColdFusion. I could just use the SSO system to authenticate, but when a user logs out of one of my systems I want to make sure I log them out of ALL my systems, but I won't know which ones they are in necessarily. Trying to do this in a practical way. The good thing is all my applications are on the same sub-domain. SO...

I set three cookies at the sub-domain level with a 30 min expiration.

- Cookie A: Contains the userid
- Cookie B: Contains a string with the expiration date/time
- Cookie C: Contains a HASH of the two with some SALT added in

My thinking is if the user tried to change the userid the HASH check would fail. If someone got on the machine and tried to change the expiration the HASH check would fail. Thus hopefully making this secure. And when someone logs out of my system I clear the cookie that's shared with all of them and if they return to any system they are forced to log in again. I verify the hash on each page load and refresh the cookie periodically to extend the expiration time.

EDIT: Additionally, if user logs into app1 and then goes to app2, I don't use the cookie to authenticate, I send them back to the SSO and only if they are still logged into the SSO do they get in. So I only use the cookie to log them out AND make sure they are still logged in. 
END EDIT

Apart from the fact that the userid is "exposed" in the cookie is this secure/where could this fail or be compromised?

I don't want to store sessions or anything like that in a DB if it can be avoided.

Comment: I've thought over this and I don't see how this presents a respectable threat (go ahead Mr. User, find the exact hash so you can extend your session time). Like you said, you're not using this to let users in, you're just using it to know if a user should be forced out (because they clicked logout in another app). It's not the key to office door, it's your boss telling he's locking up and it's time to go home.

Comment: The only possible problem, and I don't think this is an issue, it sounds like if user logs into site a, then site b, then site c, then logs out of b and back into b, they still retain their sessions in site A and site c. But since they could have logged into site A and site C themselves, this doesn't sound like a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've set it up to so if they log into app1 and then log out of the SSO via a different method, and another logs in and goes to app1, it double checks the hash and switches users even if the first users app1 session was still active.